# CLLocationManager in MapKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, cllocationmanager

If I use instance of CLLocationManager and MapKit (with showUserLocatio set to YES) in the same app , does it mean that they use two instances of CLLocationManager? There are a lot of similar questions and answers on stackoverflow, but none of them is actually proved by any facts.

Comment: why should there be two instances?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071484/iphone-mapview-showuserlocation-vs-locationupdate-function).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing `CLLocationManager` and the location system (the GPS, WiFi positioning, etc). A location manager and a map view both get their location information from the same place, the location system of the device. The map view might use a second location manager for its location, but it doesn't really matter. It's an implementation detail. You could create an app with 10 location managers, but it wouldn't use 10 times the power since they all get their location information from the same place (the location system of the device).

So it may be that a map view is using a `CLLocationManager` behind the scenes, but it shouldn't matter to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The reason why it is important for me is I want to control how accurately the MapKit displays user's current location and by that also to control the power usage.  In CLLocationManager you can do it by setting desiredAccuracy and distanceFilter.

I just made a test, that showed that the MapKit and separately made instance of CLLocationManager not interfere with each other - return different latitude and longitude.

Comment: There isn't that much that you can control with the mapview's location. Give the user a button to turn it off (an `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem`), but don't try to optimize it yourself. Make sure that user location is off when the map goes offscreen.